# Is it possible to use Firebase RemoteConfig in Flutter Web App?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to use Firebase RemoteConfig in my Flutter Web App, but when I call the method "fetchAndActivate", a strange error occurs:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
RemoteConfig.instance.fetchAndActivate();
```

Error:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'Null'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:53640/dart_sdk.js:5032:11)
    at Object.castError (http://localhost:53640/dart_sdk.js:5005:15)
    at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:53640/dart_sdk.js:5314:17)
    at Function.as (http://localhost:53640/dart_sdk.js:17870:19)
    at method_channel_firebase_remote_config.MethodChannelFirebaseRemoteConfig.new.setInitialValues (http://localhost:53640/packages/firebase_remote_config_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_remote_config.dart.lib.js:288:67)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: New version with Remote Config support on the web was released.

At this time, Remote config is not supported on Flutter Web.
[Link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/).

[image: See]

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says it supported now (2021) https://firebase.flutter.dev/
I can use it in web app after upgrading to firebase_remote_config: ^1.0.2